# What is a proper, modern and cross-browser safe method of creating JavaScript classes?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am confused with hundreds of ways of creating JS classes. One says that I should use prototypes, while others say that noone uses prototype beacuse it is "bad". On the other hand CoffeeScript uses prototypes but wraps a construction with a function whick returns itself (or something). I've seen function that returns an object, function that returns a function that returns an object etc..

I think it should be easy and no frameworks should be needed to create classes in a language - maybe I'm missing something.

There are also two (al least) ways of creating methods : `foo: function() {}` and `function foo() {}`. I've even seen those two ways in single class. The problem is that the first way results in creating annonymous functions (wich happens to be assigned to a field of an object) and debuggers say that error happened in annonymous function called by annonymous function etc.

I understand that JS is intended to be functional rather than OOP, but sometimes a class is the best way to describe a concept (e.g. a UI widget wants to be a class).

I'd be grateful for an example of proper constructed class with few words of explanation.

Comment: You can declare method as `foo: function foo() {}` and not bump into issue with debuger.

Comment: This is really problem with javascript. there is not any documentation from JS authority or if it is then it is so complicated. :(

Comment: JavaScript is a prototype-based language, so when you use constructor functions ("classes"), you're really supposed to use the prototype to add functionality. Only extending the prototype of other functions that are not your own is considered bad practice - that's like altering the code of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this article explains it well:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

This is (I believe) the correct way to use classes in a prototype based language like javascript, and gives a good explanation of the concepts. I use this approach in my projects, and it seems to work in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can consider the code that CoffeeScript produces "good":

```
// Create a "class" named Foo = create a variable that contains whatever the
// self-invoking anonymous function returns (the function avoids the pollution
// the global namespace).
var Foo = (function() {

  // Create the "class" = the constructor function that is supposed to be used
  // with the "new" keyword to create instances (objects).
  function Foo() {}

  // Add a method "bar" (that's what the prototype is for!)
  Foo.prototype.bar = function(baz) {
    // Assign the value to a member variable of the current instance (this)
    this.foobar = baz;
  };

  // ...add more stuff.

  // Return only the function, every other local variable stays in this scope.
  return Foo;

})();
```

Comment: It looks reasonably, however it is rather complicated.

Comment: In my experience, that pays off when classes get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident in using CoffeeScript, it has solid approach to classes, and gives you much clear syntax, compared to any other OOP framework at the same time.

Comment: Actually I don't want (can't) use CoffeeScript. I was just looking how  others do this.